# Propositional Logic Riddle, need help answering

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I have attached below a propositional logic riddle that I am having difficulty solving. It would be great if one of you could post a solution to this problem with some clear and concise explanations so I could understand what's going on. My professor isn't that great at teaching and I've looked at a bunch of videos and websites but am still for some reason having difficulty. Thanks a bunch!

[image]

Comment: For (a), in order to prove by contradiction, you must assume that Carla is a Knight and see that it leads you to a contradiction. For (b) you can assume one is a knight and one is a knave and also find a contradiction or else consider the two cases of both knights and both knaves and show that everything is self consistent.

Comment: Do you know how proof by contradiction works?  To show that Carla is a knave, assume that she is a knight and see where that leads you.

Comment: I understand how it works, but I was wondering whether or not there is a formal way of proving it, i.e. using propositional logic statements, or is it beyond/overkill for the scope of this problem? Thanks for the replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part a:

We assume Carla is a knight. That means she speaks the truth and Albert must also be a knight. However, now that Albert is a knight, he speaks the truth and says "Carla is a knave" which is a contradiction in the system. **Thus, Carla is a Knave.**

Part b:

Let's assume that Betty and Albert are *different*. Then there are two cases:

**Case 1** Albert is a knight and Betty is a knave: Since Albert speaks the truth, it is true that Betty is a knight, but that contradicts what we said about Betty being a knave. Not possible

**Case 2** Albert is knave and Betty is a knight: Since Betty speaks the truth, there must be two knights, however Carla is known to be a knave and Albert is assumed to be a knave which means there aren't two knights. Contradiction

Since they can't be different, either they're both knights or both knaves.

Comment: Thanks, I already understood how to do it in my head but this clarifies already what I had so thank you! But another question: is there a formal way to prove this(i.e., rules of inference/propositional logic statements)?

Comment: I must confess, I am not too familiar with propositional logic, however coming to think of it, it should not be too difficult. Try labeling the statements and writing them out algebraically and see where it leads you. Shape the arguments the same way I've shaped them above.

Answer (score 0):

I think that, if noting by $A_i$ that Albert is a knight and by $A_a$ that Albert is a knave, and idem for $B_i$ and $B_a$ etc. we can prove the assertion. Now by linking the propositions to their owner by an equation the we have for instance: $A_i=B_i\land C_a$ and $A_a=B_a\lor C_i$. There are six equations of that form. Now by properly substituting the LHS's into the RHS's one can obtain a contradiction.